# Loading an asset on HoloLens only works in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am developing a HoloLens-Application that loads assets from its internal memory. At the moment I can just access the Emulator and not the device.

```
    try
    {
        //for unity: replaced with string path = @"C:\Users\root\Desktop\cube";
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "cube.unity3d");
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            //Using the example code
            myLoadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(path);
            if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
                return;
            }
            var prefab = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>("cube");
            Instantiate(prefab);
            myLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //never reached during all tests
        Debug.Log(ex.Message);
    }
```

When I press the play-button in unity, the cube is displayed, but when I run the program in the HoloLens-emulator, it just does not work. The file exists, but the myLoadedAssetBundle is always null. In Unity I used the path to the desktop, when running on hololens I used the path in the code.
All files can ber accessed. Even the following worked fine:

```
//called after creating the string path
File.WriteAllText(path + ".txt", "This is a test");
```

I have no idea what could be the problem. The file always was in the path (I uploaded it in FileExplorer) and it was found. The file on my desktop is exactly the same as the one uploaded in the emulator.

Are there any chances that it runs on the HoloLens but not on the emulator?

**Update:**

Now I also tried it on a real HoloLens with the same Issue. I am using Unity 2017.1.0f3

Comment: My guess: `File.Exists` is returning false (in which case, nothing is done at all) or an error is being thrown at some point (in which case `Debug.Log` doesn't do anything because you're not running in the editor).

Comment: Actually, I tested it on HoloLens, same Issue. No, file.exists Returns true, I get myAssetBundle = false, it does not load the object

Comment: No idea. I didn't mess with asset bundles on the hololens while I was developing for it, but I do know that its file system is obtuse.

Comment: sorry, I meant myAssetBundle null. I just do not understand why it works in the unity-playmode and not on my hololens

Comment: Because the Hololens is weird. Also the emulator isn't 100% accurate, it's close, but it's not 100%. Take a look at [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/current_limitations_for_apps_using_apis_from_the_shell), I never tried doing anything with the file system, so I don't know what its exact limitations are.

Comment: thats what I also thought but now I used a real HoloLens since I was able to access one. Sadly I still get NULL when loading the file.

Comment: I'm not surprised (file system access *should* match, but I do know that input and visuals don't: project I was on almost screwed that up real bad). Shame though.

Comment: I tested it again: Using the same paths, i can read the file with File.ReadAllBytes, and write the same in a copy. So I am sure the file exists and can be read. Now I think there may be something with the HoloToolkit or anything else?

Comment: That sounds like a bug in Unity, if the `AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(path)` is what's not returning the desired data. I had an issue where my application would crash when it was run in the emulator (and device) but could be configured to be recoverable. Ended up being a weird bug introduced in that version of Unity (and took the Unity and Microsoft folks 3 weeks to identify).

Comment: It is possible that, since the asset is not "loaded" in the scene (it is loaded through script), the asset is not included in the pre-built package of your application (when you build in Unity). I had the same issue with an XML file containing useful information that was not loading on my HoloLens, but was loading when ran in Unity. Instead of using a path, I would suggest to link your prefab to a GameObject in your scene!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a while too.

I found it to be related to how the asset bundle is exported. Examples tend to show this -

```
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(assetBundleDirectory, buildMap, BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
```

But in order to work in the HoloLens they need to be exported like this -

```
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(assetBundleDirectory, buildMap, BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.WSAPlayer);
```